# Oracle sql: totals by date ranges and grand total in one query

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

I am trying to show total by date ranges and grand total at the end.

```
drop table EP;
create table EP (style varchar2(1), color varchar2(2), order_date date, order_qty number(2));

insert into EP values ('A','a1',to_date('01/01/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 10);
insert into EP values ('A','a2',to_date('01/01/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 12);
insert into EP values ('A','a3',to_date('01/01/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 15);
insert into EP values ('B','b1',to_date('01/05/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 5);
insert into EP values ('A','a3',to_date('01/05/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 8);
insert into EP values ('C','c1',to_date('01/06/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 3);
insert into EP values ('H','a1',to_date('01/07/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 25);
insert into EP values ('A','b3',to_date('01/07/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 10);
insert into EP values ('B','b3',to_date('01/10/2023','mm/dd/yyyy'), 15);

select * from EP;
```

I've tried using ROLLUP, but can't get it to work as I am adding more columns.
Is it possible to achieve the following result in on query?

```
Expected Result:
------------------
STYLE COLOR DATE        QTY
A     a1    1/1/2023    10
A     a2    1/1/2023    12
A     a3    1/1/2023    15
Total:                  37
B     b1    1/5/2023    5
A     a3    1/5/2023    8 
Total:                  13
C     c1    1/6/2023    3 
Total:                  3
H     a1    1/7/2023    25
A     b3    1/7/2023    10
Total:                  35
B     b3    1/10/2023   15
Total:                  15
Grand Total:            103
```

Comment: I appreciate all your responses. All solutions work, but I made my pick based on usage of ROLLUP function. I am simply trying to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select case when color is null and order_date is not null then 'Total:'
  2              when color is null and order_date is     null then 'Grand Total:'
  3              else max(style)
  4         end style,
  5  color, order_date, sum(order_qty) qty
  6  from ep
  7  group by rollup(order_date, color)
  8  order by order_date;

STYLE        COLOR      ORDER_DATE        QTY
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
A            a1         01/01/2023         10
A            a2                            12
A            a3                            15
Total:                                     37
A            a3         05/01/2023          8
B            b1                             5
Total:                                     13
C            c1         06/01/2023          3
Total:                                      3
H            a1         07/01/2023         25
A            b3                            10
Total:                                     35
B            b3         10/01/2023         15
Total:                                     15
Grand Total:                              103

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you, by any chance, use SQL*Plus, there are reporting settings you can use to get the same result:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> set pagesize 200
SQL> col style format a15
SQL> col color format a7
SQL> break on order_date on report
SQL> compute sum label "Total:"       of order_qty on order_date
SQL> compute sum label "Grand Total:" of order_qty on report
SQL> select style, color, order_date, order_qty
  2  from ep
  3  order by order_date;
```

which results in

```
STYLE           COLOR   ORDER_DATE  ORDER_QTY
--------------- ------- ---------- ----------
A               a1      01/01/2023         10
A               a2                         12
A               a3                         15
                        ********** ----------
                        Total:             37
B               b1      05/01/2023          5
A               a3                          8
                        ********** ----------
                        Total:             13
C               c1      06/01/2023          3
                        ********** ----------
                        Total:              3
H               a1      07/01/2023         25
A               b3                         10
                        ********** ----------
                        Total:             35
B               b3      10/01/2023         15
                        ********** ----------
                        Total:             15
                                   ----------
Grand Total:                              103

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps rather have the total as another column instead of row. Anyway, since you want a grand total in addition to subtotals, then I'm not sure how you would get around using at least one UNION.

```
select coalesce(style, 'Total') as style, color, order_date, order_qty
  from (
    select style, color, order_date, sum(order_qty) as order_qty, 
      grouping_id(style, color) as g1
    from EP
    group by order_date, cube(style, color)
    having(g1) in (0, 3)
    union
    select 'Grand Total', null, null, sum(order_qty), null
    from EP
)z
order by 3,1,2
```

| STYLE | COLOR | ORDER_DATE | ORDER_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a1 | 01-JAN-23 | 10 |
| A | a2 | 01-JAN-23 | 12 |
| A | a3 | 01-JAN-23 | 15 |
| Total | *null* | 01-JAN-23 | 37 |
| A | a3 | 05-JAN-23 | 8 |
| B | b1 | 05-JAN-23 | 5 |
| Total | *null* | 05-JAN-23 | 13 |
| C | c1 | 06-JAN-23 | 3 |
| Total | *null* | 06-JAN-23 | 3 |
| A | b3 | 07-JAN-23 | 10 |
| H | a1 | 07-JAN-23 | 25 |
| Total | *null* | 07-JAN-23 | 35 |
| B | b3 | 10-JAN-23 | 15 |
| Total | *null* | 10-JAN-23 | 15 |
| Grand Total | *null* | *null* | 103 |

Answer (score 0):

You UNION all results of three queries that give you the result.

But you need to add order_date to the second query for sorting pupose

usually it is best to do this in the appilcation.

```
SELECT
style,color , order_date,order_qty
FROM EP
  UNION ALL
SELECT MIN('Total:'), NULL, order_date, SUM(order_qty) qty
FROM EP
GROUP BY order_date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total:', NULL, NULL, SUM(order_qty)
  FROM EP
ORDER BY 3,4,2;
```

| STYLE | COLOR | ORDER_DATE | ORDER_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a1 | 01-JAN-23 | 10 |
| A | a2 | 01-JAN-23 | 12 |
| A | a3 | 01-JAN-23 | 15 |
| Total: | *null* | 01-JAN-23 | 37 |
| B | b1 | 05-JAN-23 | 5 |
| A | a3 | 05-JAN-23 | 8 |
| Total: | *null* | 05-JAN-23 | 13 |
| C | c1 | 06-JAN-23 | 3 |
| Total: | *null* | 06-JAN-23 | 3 |
| A | b3 | 07-JAN-23 | 10 |
| H | a1 | 07-JAN-23 | 25 |
| Total: | *null* | 07-JAN-23 | 35 |
| B | b3 | 10-JAN-23 | 15 |
| Total: | *null* | 10-JAN-23 | 15 |
| Grand Total: | *null* | *null* | 103 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AyzDYWw8)

Answer (score 0):

To replicate the expected result, try along:

```
with
Data(sortorder, STYLE, COLOR, "DATE", QTY) as (
  select
    to_char(order_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    || ' 0 '
    || to_char(100 - ascii(style))
    || ' '
    || color as sortorder,
    style,
    color,
    replace(ltrim(to_char(order_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), '0'), '/0', '/'),
    order_qty
  from EP
  union all
  select
    to_char(order_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || ' 1 ',
    'Total:',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    sum(order_qty)
  from EP
  group by order_date
  union all
  select
    '9999-99-99',
    'Grand Total:',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    sum(order_qty)
  from EP
)
select
  STYLE, COLOR, "DATE", QTY from Data order by sortorder
;
```

This caters for some of Oracle's peculiarities.
But - just as a word of caution - as it stands, it doesn't lend itself particularly well for further processing by the database engine...

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f04c/1)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.